# How can I export YouTube's personal history?

Tags: youtube

In YouTube, we can click on "History" and see the videos we've been playing from the most recent to the earlier plays.

I spent the night listening to a friend selecting music from YouTube and I want to get a list of the links he played so I can listen to them again at home.

[image]

Comment: Contact Google and request this feature be added

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are only rather ugly workarounds for this one AFAIK. But here they are:

- http://google.com/takeout lets you download your data. All of it, including the watch history. After download, you can send that to your friend. It's most likely in JSON though which is handy for programming stuff but not so nice to read as a human.
- Manually go through the watch history (opening links in a new tab is useful here) and add each of them to a playlist. If this playlist is public, your friend can access it later on.

Comment: Just for anyone wondering, at the moment, Google Takeout actually provides HTML (Human-readable) version of Watch and Search History.

Comment: So YouTube has two channels one with your full name and another one which was there before YouTube was acquired by Google. I am getting the watch history of only one of the channels via takeout. How to get the other one?

Comment: It's now possible to choose between HTML and JSON formats. This choice applies for both search history and watching history.

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to http://google.com/takeout
2. Select "deselect all" at the top
3. Scroll to bottom and select "YouTube and YouTube Music"
4. Then select "All YouTube data included" underneath the "YouTube and YouTube Music" option
5. Select "deselect all" (again) inside this popup
6. Select "history", then "ok"
7. Select "Next step", leave "export once" selected
8. Leave .zip selected and 2GB selected (the download will only be a few MB)
9. You may have to check your email to verify you requested this takeout (I had too)
10. The download should be ready in a few minutes, refresh the page at https://takeout.google.com/ and you will see a "Download" button [image: Download button of takeout at takeout.google.com]
11. Download and extract, the watch history will be an HTML file called watch-history.html inside the Takeout > YouTube and YouTube Music > history folder that you can open in your web browser, which looks like this:
12. [image: Interface of YouTube's Watch History Takeout]

Comment: Thanks, really helpful

Comment: Yes, very helpful, and again verified this still works splendidly.